# почему Java stack memory быстрее heap

Tags: java

почему доступ к объектам в стэке быстрее чем к объектам вне стэка ?

Comment: а в яве есть объекты в стеке?

Comment: ну да, сначала напридумывают всяких джав, а потом делают из них с++

Comment: А он быстрее? По большому счету стэки, кучи и т.д. есть детали реализации конкретной виртуальной машины. Скорость, соответственно зависит от реализации и настроек.

Comment: @zRrr пишут что благодаря escape analysis  локально созданные объекты нет смысла хранить в хипе , т.к. их область видимости - только метод, поэтому они могут храниться в стэке

Comment: @voipp в hotspot нет создания объектов на стеке, scalar replacement - это несколько другое: http://dev.cheremin.info/2016/02/stack-allocation-vs-scalar-replacement.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Управление памятью для стека тривиально: машина просто увеличивает или уменьшает одно значение, так называемый «указатель стека» (stack pointer). Управление памятью для кучи сложнее: память, выделенная в куче, освобождается в произвольные моменты, а каждая область выделенной в куче памяти может быть произвольного размера. Распределителю памяти, как правило, требуется приложить гораздо больше усилий для определения областей, которые можно использовать заново.

Comment: в вопросе речь не о выделении, а о доступе. Наверное, все же по скорости доступа разницы быть не должно. И там, и там память.

Comment: выделение памяти как раз таки быстрое в яве, всего лишь увеличить указатель. скорей всего речь о том, что при последовательном выделении нескольких блоков памяти - на стэке они будут рядышком (и лучше закэшируются процессором), а в куче - могут оказаться и далеко друг от друга (в разных предварительно выделенных больших блоках памяти)